# Could not pre-select on Kendo UI Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, user-interface, kendo-ui

I'd like to ask on why I could not pre-select on a KendoMultiSelect if I use this code?

If I declare **var tagIds = ["100", "200"];** or something like that, and get rid of this line:

**$.each(selectedWorkgroups.split(','), function(i, elem) { tagIds.push(elem); });**

...it works.

Anybody who could help me please? :( THANKS IN ADVANCE! :D

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var list = [{label: "", value: ""}];

   <c:forEach var="w" items="${filteredWGs}">      
          list.push({label: "${w.name}", value: "${w.id}"});
   </c:forEach>

   var tagIds = [];

   var selectedStuff = "${element.stuff}";

   $.each(selectedStuff.split(','), function(i, elem) { tagIds.push(elem); });

   $("#multiSelect").kendoMultiSelect({                    
          dataTextField: "label",
       dataValueField: "value",
       dataSource: list,
       value: tagIds, placeholder: "Please select or type...",
       change: function() {
           // change
       }  
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RK911, was right. It seems that tagIds was an OBJECT array. I had to change them to *.toString() from the java files I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

How to select values programatically (via the methods of the ms API) for the MultiSelect is covered in this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/multiselect/api.html).

Comment: I have tried every trivial initialization I could find on the internet, but I couldn't get it done. When I initialize hard coded values, it works. Very strange.

Comment: demonstrate your case with an example.

Comment: My guess is that the tagIds is not a value array. You are probably getting object array.

Comment: Or you are getting list of "label", can you post the content of the tagIds you see in debugger?

Comment: it's ["100", "200"] in the debugger.

Comment: RK, you were right. It seems that tagIds was an OBJECT array. I had to change them to *.toString() from the java files I was working on. GOOD STUFF! THANKS! +1